# NodeJS express get request sends me first to my default website url

Tags: node.js, api, express, get, router

I have a function that simply redirects

```
app.get('/image', function(req,res) {

    let address = req.query.address; 
    let accesories = req.query.acc || null; 
    let format = req.query.format || null;
    let background = req.query.bg || null;

    let api_url = 'https://bananomonkeys.herokuapp.com/image?address=' + address
    if(background) api_url += '&bg=' + background;
    if(accesories) api_url += '&acc=' + accesories;
    if(format) api_url += '&format=' + format;

    res.redirect(api_url);
});
```

When I use it a weird thing happens.
The default website is www.monkeygen.com.
When I try to do something like www.monkeygen.com/image?address= from any website other then monkeygen.com  It just opens www.monkeygen.com. 
When I try it when i am inside www.monkeygen.com I get the desired results. 
Why would it act that way? This endpoint should give me an image and its useless if 3rd parties will just open the main website first.

an example address to use in the parameter is ban_1m5z1cr49tenswk6sxfuoao4jcbkame5yxmjjyjka3za4id9ktcc6s9af8bi

Comment: Is there any configuration of cors?

Comment: I do not believe cors are the issue here. They are configured

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why to access the url just from within the site.

Comment: You and me both

Comment: So I tested here and the redirection is working. [Link](http://www.monkeygen.com/image?address=ban_1m5z1cr49tenswk6sxfuoao4jcbkame5yxmjjyjka3za4id9ktcc6s9af8bi)